# Two contexts in LINQ join

Tags: c#, linq

There are two contexts in my LINQ and Lambda join, to retrieve data from another entity. The below code sequence runs into “The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts” exception.

```
    BusinessSupportEntity context = new BusinessSupportEntity();
    BusinessSupportEntity contextLan = new BusinessSupportEntity();

        CollectionViewSource viewLanParametersSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("viewLanParametersSource")));        
        contextLan.parParameters.Join(
                context.cliClient,
                par => par.parUid,
                cli => cli.cliParUid,
                (par, cli) => new { Par = par, Cli = cli })
                .Where(par => par.Par.parUid == par.Cli.cliParUid)
         .Load();
```

As a result do I need the language assigned to a particular client as in the SQL statement.

```
SELECT p.parDescription
FROM cliClient c
INNER JOIN parParameters p
ON c.cliParUid = p.parUid
```

How can I separate the second context in a way to execute the statement successfully?

Comment: Why do you have two contexts in the first place?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but It seems that both your context are pointing to same database.

Comment: Hi Dai, the language data is saved in entity “parParameters” and the data from parParameters entity is retrieved in “cliClient” entity

Comment: Hi Ashu, correct, both entities are pointing to the same database

Comment: So both tables are in the same database, no need for two contexts. Use only `context` and remove `contextLan`.

Comment: Thanks a million for such prompt solution René Vogt. I tried a lot, but using one entity only haven’t come up to my empty brain.